# Kill Python script after 60 second in simplest way

Tags: python

I have python script and want to stop work or kill proccess after 60 second of execution .
not just stop work , kill or die proccess.
Don't find a good reference for this .

**P.S**: Kill python script itself (like a timer with first line of script to kill script after a time)
**P.S2**: I'm on windows and want compile it to .exe
**P.S3**: Python is on version 2.7

Comment: Kill it from the Python program itself? From the command line?

Comment: Yes , Kill python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *nix, you may use alarm clock:

```
import signal  
signal.alarm(TIME_TO_DIE)
# your code goes on
```

Under windows, you may use start your job as a daemon thread, while the main thread sleep 60s and then quit. e.g.(not tested under windows):

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

thrd = Thread(target=you_function_to_run)
thrd.daemon = True
thrd.start()
sleep(60)
```

Comment: whats the `TIME_TO_DIE` format , is it in Milliseconds or seconds ?

Comment: @root seconds, see: [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm)

Comment: I give a error : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'alarm'`

Comment: @root `signal` module is not available in Windows. You may use daemon threads. see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks dlutxx What's the `you_function_to_run` ?

Comment: @root Since the main thread is for timing, you have to run your actual code to in a daemon thread, which will die when the main thread is done. And I meant `your_function_to_run`, like `main` or something.

Comment: @latheiere Daemon threads will die as soon as the main thread is done. Could you give me an example, such that I can test it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can try this:

`(cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 60; kill $cmdpid) & exec YOUR_COMMAND)`

for example, if you want to execute a program named script.py:

`(cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 60; kill $cmdpid) & exec python script.py)`

Comment: I'm on windows , and want to compile it to exe

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import os, sys
import threading

pid = os.getpid()
def quit_system():
    os.system('kill %d'%pid)

t = threading.Timer(5.0, quit_system)
t.start()

while(True):
    1 + 1
```

Comment: Looks to work , but cant kill or die script from command prompt :`Port: 'kill' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`